# How can I animate process 1 circle transform to other and create a shape along the way in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, transform

I have a task with WPF 3D Animation:
I have 2 circle with known center point, radius, and perpendicular with the known vector.
The circle 1 will need to smoothly 'transform' to circle 2 and I want to animate that transform process and create a shape along the way (a twisted tube with different radius).Anyone has idea or suggestion code to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a smooth spline path from one center point to the next, or just a straight line?

Comment: Hi bde, I updated my question to make it clearer